# How to use Java 11 Java Flight Recorder JFR library with Wildfly 16

Tags: java, wildfly, profiling, jfr, wildfly-16

**Background**

I'm working on `jboss/wildfly 16` servlet mypackagex.war.
It's a `maven` project. My server uses `openjdk11-jdk`.
I managed to run the produce a java flight recording using jcmd. And managed to open that jfr dump with JDK Mission Control. All nice and dandy.

```
JPID=616
jcmd $JPID JFR.configure repositorypath=/tmp/jcmdrecording/
jcmd $JPID JFR.start settings=default.jfc name=recording1 filename=JFRfile.jfr disk=true dumponexit=true  maxage=2d maxsize=2000m  path-to-gc-roots=true
jcmd $JPID JFR.check
jcmd $JPID JFR.dump /tmp/recording1.jfr
```

**The Issue**

When I tried to do a custom event recording programmatically like the example below. I get an error. It's as if wildfly don't know `jdk.jfr.Event` exists. **What did I miss?**

**Declaring a custom event recorder example**

```
package com.mypackagex.dao;

import jdk.jfr.Category;
import jdk.jfr.Event;
import jdk.jfr.Label;
import jdk.jfr.Period;

@Label("Database stats")
@Period("1 s")
@Category("Database")
public class DatabaseStatsEvent extends Event {
}
```

**Code location to take the flight recording event**

```
public class UrlObjectActionMapperDAO {
    private static String jndiDataSourceName = "jdbc/cedar_mypackagex_security";
    private static DataSource dataSource = getDataSourceFromJNDI();
    
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UrlObjectActionMapperDAO.class);

    private static DataSource getDataSourceFromJNDI() {

        return DatasourceProvider.getProvider().getDsSecurity();
    }
    
    public UrlObjectActionMapperDTO getURLMappedProps(String URI){
        
        DatabaseStatsEvent ev =  new DatabaseStatsEvent();         // --------- line 49 the issue!
        ev.begin();
        
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

**The error**
Scroll to the right where you'll see `jdk/jfr/Event`

```
local-mypackagex            | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/mypackagex/dao/DatabaseStatsEvent (Module "deployment.mypackagex.war" from Service Module Loader): jdk/jfr/Event
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.dao.UrlObjectActionMapperDAO.getURLMappedProps(UrlObjectActionMapperDAO.java:49)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.services.RBACService.getURLMappedProps(RBACService.java:70)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.servlet.RBACFilter.validateRequest(RBACFilter.java:465)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.servlet.RBACFilter.validateRequest(RBACFilter.java:450)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.servlet.RBACFilter.doFilter(RBACFilter.java:235)
local-mypackagex            |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
local-mypackagex            |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//com.mypackagex.servlet.ProxyResponseBuilderFilter.doFilter(ProxyResponseBuilderFilter.java:456)
local-mypackagex            |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
local-mypackagex            |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
local-mypackagex            |   at deployment.mypackagex.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
```

Comment: jdk.jfr is located in boot layer and it should be accessible in JDK 11. If you have created a custom JDK image (using jlink) without the jdk.jfr module, you would see this, or if WildFly uses a custom class loader that prevents JFR to be accessed. FWIW, you are missing ev.commit(), but it doesn't explain the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could solve it in Wildfly 15 (using Java 11):

Make sure your [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.wildfly.org/15/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file) contains:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="jdk.jfr"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But beware, I got this mostly via trial-and-error and don't wholly understand the consequences and why jdk.jfr is not included by default.

I also don't know how this works out on other wildfly versions.

Answer (score -1):

I had the identical hassle and will resolve it in Wildfly 15 (the use of Java 11) But beware, I were given this by and large through trial-and-mistakess and don`t absolutely apprehend the outcomes and why jdk.jfr isn't covered via way of means of default. I additionally do not know how this works out on different wildly versions[.](https://davidphotography.com.au/who-should-a-bride-take-photos-with-at-the-wedding-venue/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31423175)